# import pandas as pd error - module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'artist'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have a single line shell in jupyter notebook

```
import pandas as pd
```

Which on running produce the error

```
module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'artist'
```

Doesn't these two packages 'matplotlib' and 'pandas' independent? Why am i getting this error?

Comment: try restarting the IDE. You may also have a look here. https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/12626

Comment: restarting ide is not solving the problem.

Comment: The link says to  update matplotlib to 3.0.1. which also doesn't solve the problem

Comment: you can add your issue on the same page, if upgrading still doesn't help

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known issue on GitHub](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/12626). Pandas relies on matplotlib for its plotting functions. To fix it, run this in your jupyter terminal to update to the newest version of both modules:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade matplotlib pandas
```

Comment: Also restart the kernel in the notebook menu.

Comment: This is not working. I have tried it. Still the same error.

Comment: Can you run: `import matplotlib` and `matplotlib.__version__` then post the output?

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name 'get_backend' on import matplotlib

Comment: As suggested in the comment on your question, you need to figure out what kernel (environment) you're using.

Answer (score 0):

it still exists after run

```
python -m pip install --upgrade matplotlib pandas
```

then create a file `~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc` and add the following code:

```
backend: TkAgg
```